# Confused by how "pass in by value" works

Tags: java, reference, arguments

I'm new to Java and am confused by how "pass in by value" works.

```
int[] a;

public Constructor(int[] anArrayOfInt){ 
    a = anArrayOfInt;
}
```

does variable `a` point to the object passed into the constructor? Do changes to variable `a` reflect in the object that is passed into the constructor?

Comment: "*Do changes to variable a reflect in the object that is passed into the constructor?*" - Should be easy to check that yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does variable a points to the object passed into the Constructor?

Answer is yes.

> Does changes to variable a reflects in the object that is passed into the Constructor?

Answer is yes.

Because in java, parameter is passed by value. When you pass a object to method, actual, you are passing a reference of object.

Comment: this is where I'm a bit confused, if java pass in by value, shouldn't it create a copy of the passed in object (which is distinct to the original passed in object) and assign variable 'a' to the copied object? apology for asking a simple question like this, but i'm so confused about it

Comment: @TonyStark No, it makes a copy of the reference, or in the case of primitives (`int`, `long`, `boolean`, etc) a copy of the value.